# Python Regex to find a word between first two whitespaces

Tags: python, regex

I have some file creation time data in format.

```
Thu Jan  2 17:05:37 2020
Thu Feb 27 11:17:14 2020
```

I want to extract only the month out of this string ( Jan, Feb) in the output and remove other string.

I have tried the following regex

```
^\S*\s+(\S+)
```

It is giving me an output like (Thu Feb), but i require only the month part.

Comment: FYI, why not convert it to datetime object & extract what ever fields required ```datetime.strptime("Thu Jan  2 17:05:37 2020", "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y").strftime("%b")```

Comment: `match.group(1)` after running `re.search` already contains the value you need.

Answer (score 1):

Other way around is to let `dateutil` to parse it for you:

```
import dateutil.parser as dparser

l = ['Thu Jan  2 17:05:37 2020', 'Thu Feb 27 11:17:14 2020']

months = [dparser.parse(i, fuzzy=True).strftime("%b") for i in l]
months
```

Output:

```
['Jan', 'Feb']
```

Comment: Couldn't agree with you more.

Answer (score 0):

You can try The split()

```
L="Thu Jan  2 17:05:37 2020"
print(L.split()[1])
```

Comment: ``Split`` by default will split by spaces, there is no need to explicity passing spaces.

Comment: Re @Sushanth's comment, `split()` will split on any amount of whitespace, while `split(" ")` will split on a single space.

Comment: @alaniwi, agreed for above use case just split() should be enough.

Comment: @Sushanth Yes the question seems to imply any amount of whitespace, given OP's use of `\s+`, so I agree that `split()` is the correct one here.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

str = "Thu Jan  2 17:05:37 2020"

print(re.sub("^\S*\s+(\S+)\s.*", r"\1", str))
```

Gives:

```
Jan
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is different form your requirement. If you only look for spaces then it can misbehave for months. If you want to extract the months i'll write a small simple snippet for you.

```
import calendar
import re
months=[calendar.month_abbr[i] for i in range(1,13)]

txt=["Thu Jan  2 17:05:37 2020","Thu Feb 27 11:17:14 2020"]


for j in txt:
    print([(j,i)  for i in months if len(re.findall(i,j))>0])
```

Output:

```
[('Thu Jan  2 17:05:37 2020', 'Jan')]
[('Thu Feb 27 11:17:14 2020', 'Feb')]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather simple solution:

```
import re

str = "Thu Jan  2 17:05:37 2020"
print(re.match("^\S{3}\ (\S{3})", str).group(1))
```

**Outputs:** "Jan"

Without manipulating the original string.

Answer (score -1):

You have captured the month, why not use it?

`enter code here`str = "Thu Jan  2 17:05:37 2020"
`enter code here`p = r"^\S*\s+(\S+)\s.*"
`enter code here`t = re.search(p,str)
`enter code here`print("$1:",t.group(1))

Comment: Add some code to demonstrate your thought.

Comment: That is a question not an answer ;)